# Inkscape Not Showing New Fonts, New Fonts are Available in all Other Programs

Tags: windows-10, fonts, inkscape

I have Windows 10 & Inkscape 0.92.4. New fonts that I installed 2 months ago show up in Inkscape but not the fonts that I've installed in the last 2 weeks. I've seen fixes that say to "Install for all users". Since I'm the only user on my laptop, will this fix work for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It's also called "install as administrator".